# Can't change document root in MAMP Pro

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro, document-root

I have version 3.3 of MAMP Pro.  When I click the icon to change the document root for one of my virtual hosts, it shows all of the blue folders in my Finder as grayed out.  There is one exception, I am able to go into Applications/MAMP/htdocs and successfully select that directory.

Why are all the rest of my directories grayed out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems a permission rights issue.

Check who is the runner of your Mamp services in settings (usually you or www/sql).

Check the permissions applied for folders you want to use as document root.

Change permissions to allow the "services runner" to read and write in this folder.

If necessary add this user in `Get info` window of this folder by clicking `Alt` and `+` button at the bottom left of window.

It works for me by adding **_www** (@ **World Wide Web Server**) group to read and write.

Hope this helps.